# Timer Interrupts and Process Ticks

Tags: linux, timer, linux-kernel, embedded, linux-device-driver

I was going through the LDD3 when I stumbled across the below statement.

"Timer interrupts are generated by the system's timing hardware at regular intervals; this interval is programmed at boot time by the kernel according to the value of HZ, which is an architecture-dependent value defined in  or a subplatform file included by it."

What my thought was that the timer interrupts had to solely to do with the processor speed and its a non-configurable entity. Now this statement confuses me. Can somebody please explain it to me.

Answer (score 1):

On core timer hardware is generally a digital frequency divider programmed to take input frequency as CPU clock frequency and output is a fraction of input frequency. CPU clock frequency is not programmable but the timer hardware i.e frequency divider is programmed on the basis of value of HZ to interrupt the core periodically. [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_divider

Comment: Nithin, Thanks for the answer. So you mean the fraction here is the HZ value in linux kernel which is defined as 1000? If this is so, then does that mean the timer interrupt will generate a interrupt with a frequency of f(out) where f(out)=f(in)/1000?

Comment: The fraction depends on the CPU specification. the fout is 1000 interrupts per second. fin is cpu frequency / bus clock frequecy that is not configurable